# What is the fastest way to locate javadoc of specific Eclipse RCP or SWT class?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Main help entry http://help.eclipse.org/ is bizarre.

They have good content tree, but bad search.

For example, if search for `ViewPart`, then there will be no link to this class' page found. Closest finding will be "Package org.eclipse.ui.part" page. But one can't guess apriori that it contains the requested class.

Is it possible to get "All classes" page as in Javadoc?

Search via Package Index is also long.

Comment: No help document is good. You can set the search scope. Then your search will be limited to that scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are on a javadoc page such as [this one](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Foverview-summary.html), you can click on "FRAMES" to show all the packages and classes:

[image]

Note: this generally works with any online javadoc document.

Comment: Cool! And is it possible to disable TOC?

Comment: @SuzanCioc You can hide it with the little button on the top right.